# xampp uninstall

Tags: xampp, software-uninstall

when I trying to uninstall the xampp server, then showing the dialog box with the message.[image: can anyone solve this problem?]

OS. Ubuntu 19.10 (with windows 10)

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Are you also using Windows Subsystem for Linux? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0):

To add or remove apps from the command line, you need to preface the command with [sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/sudo.8.html). See https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/